# Edit a shell prefix while the user is typing

Tags: java, shell

I'm using a BufferedReader to read lines from the terminal:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String cmd;
String displayTime;

while(true)
{
     System.out.print(displayTime +  "> ");

     cmd = in.readLine();

     // Process cmd
}
```

The goal is to have the shell prefix display time remaining until expiration of something. I have a separate thread updating the string `displayTime` every second in a sequence like "5:00", "4:49", ... by executing (int its run() method)

```
while(true)
{
     Thread.sleep(1000);
     decrement(displayTime);
     System.out.print("\r" + displayTime +  "> ");
}
```

The carriage return "\r" ar the beginning of the print statement achieves what I want, except that when the user is typing, when the carriage return interrupts them their cursor will reset to the beginning and they will start replacing the characters they had already typed before (although the BufferedReader still contains the correct command, visually it is wrong).

For example, the result of typing "listfiles":

```
l
li
lis
list
fist   <-- carriage return happens here
fist
filt
file
files
```

Is there a way to edit the shell prefix and then return to the same cursor position where the user was typing before so that they can resume seamlessly?

Comment: What is the terminal that you use (vt100/vt102/xterm ?). There are escape sequences for each one. Note however that output is not "atomic". it is possible that the user will type character in the exact millisecond when the date is updated.

Comment: I am using xterm-256color on a Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the input comes from regular input (e.g., no curses, readline, etc), the following escape sequence can be used for VT100 compatible terminals (including most xterms, vt102 and other terminal emulators). The ESC is the escape (`\033`)

- Save Cursor `ESC 7`
- Restore Curosr 'ESC 8`

The println should look something like:

```
     System.out.print("\0337\r" + displayTime +  "> \0338");
```

You will also have to ensure that System.out is not buffered.